# Google Admin SDK PHP cannot create user. Not Authorized

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk

I'm having a problem implementing Google Admin SDK in PHP. It always give error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST 
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (403) Not Authorized to access this
 resource/api' in ..\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 79
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php

session_start();
/* * **********************************************
  Make an API request authenticated with a service
  account.
 * ********************************************** */
set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Directory.php';

/* * **********************************************
  ATTENTION: Fill in these values! You can get
  them by creating a new Service Account in the
  API console. Be sure to store the key file
  somewhere you can get to it - though in real
  operations you'd want to make sure it wasn't
  accessible from the webserver!
  The name is the email address value provided
  as part of the service account (not your
  address!)
  Make sure the Books API is enabled on this
  account as well, or the call will fail.
 * ********************************************** */
$client_id = 'my_client_id'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = 'email'; //Email Address 
$key_file_location = 'key.p12'; //key.p12

if ($client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>' || !strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("appname");
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

/* * **********************************************
  If we have an access token, we can carry on.
  Otherwise, we'll get one with the help of an
  assertion credential. In other examples the list
  of scopes was managed by the Client, but here
  we have to list them manually. We also supply
  the service account
 * ********************************************** */
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'), $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();


/* * **********************************************
  We're just going to make the same call as in the
  simple query as an example.
 * ********************************************** */    

$familyName = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'familyname');
$givenName = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'givenname');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');
$primaryEmail = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email');

$user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
$name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();

$name->setFamilyName($familyName);
$name->setGivenName($givenName);

$user->setName($name);
$user->setHashFunction("MD5");
$user->setPrimaryEmail($primaryEmail);
$user->setPassword(hash("md5", $password));

$result = $service->users->insert($user);
```

There is no documentation and I'm very confused with this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem until I set the "sub" account on the credentials object which is the email address for the administrative user that you want to perform the API action as.

So in Google Apps Admin for your domain I assume you've created a user and added them to and admin role that has API access to users right? In your code above you just need to add (with correct email address of course):

```
$cred->sub = "adminuser@domain.com";
```

Add that right before:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
```

I did a full example for someone else that you might be able to reference too: https://gist.github.com/fillup/9fbf5ff35b337b27762a

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but found a solution to this by going through this blog

http://michaelseiler.net/2014/12/16/google-admin-sdk-api-with-php/

Assuming you have done all the necessary setting up on the Admin Console (i.e. delegating domain authority), then pay particular attention to the line

```
`$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account_name, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'), $key);`
```

this should be:

```
`$user_to_impersonate = 'adminaccount@example.com';$scopes =array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user');$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
 $service_account_name,
 $scopes,
 $key,
 'notasecret', // Default P12 password
 'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
 $user_to_impersonate);`
```

I changed that and boom....

Answer (score 0):

I think i was receiving this error when i tried to query a user.

During the creation of the JWT_CLAIM portion of the assertion, you must specify a domain admin account that your service account can impersonate...  this part was poorly documented, i thought.

i dont know exactly how the google php library does it, but i didnt see anywhere in your code where you specify that account email address.  if you have looked at the oauth2 documentation, in the jwt_claim secion, there is an "additional claims" subsection that says:

*To obtain an access token that grants an application delegated access to a resource, include the email address of the user in the JWT claim set as the value of the sub field.*

I had to include that admin email account in the creation of my assertion before i could even query the directory.users API.

i apologize if this isnt helpful, but im not using the library for php, im building my own (with php).